# Algorithm to find min cut given max flow

Tags: algorithm

Can anyone give me an idea about the algorithm to find min cut in a graph (V,E,c,s,t,f) where f[v][w] is max flow and c[v][w] is capacity?

Comment: Google ?  There's tons of stuff out there, what exactly are you having a problem with ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find the minimum cut on a graph using a maximum flow algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482986/how-can-i-find-the-minimum-cut-on-a-graph-using-a-maximum-flow-algorithm)

Comment: This is a real question. Those who closed it don't understand the max-flow min-cut theorem.

Answer (score 4):

Run a BFS or DFS from the source node. The edges where you cannot go to the right, sits on the min cut. When traversing edges you have to check if `c[v][w] > f[v][w]`. The nodes you could reach lie on the left side of the min cut and other nodes are on the right side.

Comment: You can check more details [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cts=1331121392192&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Bjsessionid%3D6F1324E4CAF290676E3605F39901D1A4%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.85.7307%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=tkxXT7v-EsrJrAeZwLXzCw&usg=AFQjCNHlUpzr2bHRgY9ecDnxpKDyRgp9Pw&sig2=6P1qlsU54JAjBmMVScfd7Q)

Comment: http://ezekiel.vancouver.wsu.edu/~cs223/lectures/graphs/maxflow/maxflow.pdf

Comment: NOTE: If you do not want to implement the algorithm yourself. And I would recommend you don't unless you just want to study, then use JGraphT library. Problem solved perfectly - MaxFlow and MinCut all delivered to you via perfectly elegant API.

Comment: Not entirely true if there are circular flows in the graph. If the circular flow is saturated, then it will block you from continuing there, but it has no relation to whether the sink can be reached.