# how to use Dinic's algorithm to find min-cut edges in undireted graph?

Tags: algorithm, max-flow, undirected-graph

I am looking for an algorithm, when a given two nodes 's' and 't' in a undiredted graph, to find min-cut edges, which partitions the graph into two A and B, 's' will in A and 't' will in B.

I see most people suggesting for Ford–Fulkerson algorithm to for  that task, at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482986/how-can-i-find-the-minimum-cut-on-a-graph-using-a-maximum-flow-algorithm/21219223#21219223). I am thinking is that is it possible to use Dinic's algorithm for it. Since Dinic's algorithm can be speed up with dynamic tree. Because I want to find min-cut edges with fastest way possible.

which algorithm is faster for to find min-cut edges in a huge undirected graph?

I would like to hear some advice while I am looking into the details for these algorithm.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, any algorithm which solves the maximal flow, also solves the minimal cut. Once you have the flows, find the [residual flow graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network). In this graph, run [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) from the source *s*. The min cut is just the set of edges *(u, v)* for which *u* is reachable from *s*, and *v* is not.

Since [Dinic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinic%27s_algorithm) is only *O(V<sup>2</sup>E)* as opposed to FF's *Θ(E<sup>2</sup>V)*, then it will be faster, in general.

The cost of finding the residual flow graph and running BFS is negligible, in this case.

Comment: Originally I applied modified dfs to find all simple paths and compute min-cut edges from these paths, but it is quite slow when graph become larger. Great answer, this gives me confidence in applying Dinic with dynamic tree for this problem. Thanks :). I hope this solution output edges faster.

Comment: @alim it is known that DTs are inferior in practice in terms of running time, so don't even bother... Use a good push relabel implementation instead

Comment: @ Niklas B, Hi, I am not very familiar with these algorithms, could you please be more specific. are you suggesting to use a different algorithm or ?

Comment: @alim The table [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Solutions) outlines various known solutions. You can find it there.

Comment: @Ami Tavory, yes, I see the table, the Jim Orlin's + KRT (King, Rao, Tarjan)'s algorithm seems faster than others, since its time complexity  O(VE). I just want to use an algorithm which always correctly compute and as fast as possible (simple is better too). Maybe I should check that algorithm. Some algorithm has example codes and while some bit difficut to find such sources.

Comment: @Ami Tavory, Hi, one last question I wan to ask. My graph is undirected and unweighted graph. I guess i can assign same weight on each edge, then these algorithm should be able to compute min-cut edges. Am I right?

Comment: @alim Technically, you should convert your graph into a digraph (directed graph) with antiparallel edges each with capacity 1.

Comment: @Ami Tavory, you been helpful, thank you very much :)

Comment: @Niklas B. Yes, I found dynamic tree is kind of trouble, push relabel algorithm seems easier, such I don't have to use complex data structure.

Comment: @alim not only easier, also faster in practice. Check out http://www.davideisenstat.com/dtree/

Comment: @Niklas B. Wow, the tree thing is quite complicated. I should have check push-relabel earlier. But it seems I need to do few changes to make push-relabel to find min-cuts, not max-flow which is not goal.

Comment: @alim Computing the min-cut is actually simpler: After you computed a maximum preflow using push-relabel, every "gap" (height label with no associated vertices) represents a minimum cut

Comment: @NiklasB. I posted a question about min-cut by push-relabeling algorithm, and a example in figure here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216258/how-to-apply-push-relabel-algorithm-to-find-min-cut-edges-in-undirected-unweight?noredirect=1#comment60064998_36216258   . could you take a look and point out in that example? that would be great if you could.

Comment: @NiklasB. I did not understand what does 'height label with no associated vertices' mean, could you explain in the example I posted? Thanks