# implement push relabel algorithm s-t min-cut edges for undirected unweighted graph

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for a good solution to find s-t min-cut edges in undirected and unweighted graph. I want to use push-relabel algorithm.

But I am not sure how to implement it to find min-cut on undirected and unweighted graph. 
Having two edges in reverse between each pair of vertices and given same weight on all edges, and apply the push-relabel algorithm ?
can I get min-cut in that way?

I tried it on the following graph. a(m,n) on vertex means e(a)=m,h(a)=n. and every edge capacity is set as 1.

[image]

clearly the min-cut is the edge (c,t). but from the last pic, how can I know (c,t) is the min-cut edges? or did I computed in wrong way.

Could anyone point out my mistake here?
Advises are welcomed, thanks!

Comment: Yes, that will work.

Comment: @HenryLee, I updated the question and added an example, could you take a look at it? I think I am doing wrong at somewhere

Comment: @AmiTavory, I think I draw residual flow graph on above example, but mit-cut seems not right in it

Comment: @AmiTavory, you mean I computed wrong? But I read some example and followed the idea. which part I made mistake? I can't see that

Comment: @alim In the diagrams above, where are the node heights at each step?

Comment: @AmiTavory, i.e, (1,2), 1 is the excess and 2 is the height. I just showed first 2 steps and last result. I think after pushing from 's' to 'a' and 'b', also we can push from 'a' and 'b' to 's' back, until heights stop us from doing that.  so at last, the result will be as shown at the right down corner. am I wrong at somewhere?

Comment: The labels 1,2,3,4 are gaps, because there is no vertex with those labels at the end of the algorithm. Any of those represents the same min-cut, namely S = {s,a,b,c} and T = {t}. All the edges from S to T in the original graphs are cut edges, in this case only the edge (c, t)

Comment: For a good implementation of push-relabel, check out HI-PR and F_PRF from http://www.avglab.com/andrew/soft.html

Comment: Hi @alim. Because you are doing a undirected graph, for each edge (a, b), you should have both (a, b) and (b, a) in your original graph and both of them in your residual graph. Sorry I am not familiar with the push label algorithm, but it should at least work for the Ford-Fulkerson.

Comment: @HenryLee. Yes, I understand two edges for between two nodes work for ford-fulkerson. I think Niklas B's explanation work for this push -relabel algorithm. Thanks :)

Comment: @NiklasB. Hi, what you mean is in push-relabel algorithm, to find min-cut edges, I should check their heights, if there is gaps heights of two nodes, then means the edge between these two nodes are a cut, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find gap between heights of nodes, then by the cap find edges which are min-cut edges.